# Creating an SSL Certificate

Tags: security-certificate, certificate-generation, vpn

I have a barracuda SSL VPN.  I also have a website hosted on winhost.com.  On my website, I have a link to login to my VPN.  I always get the "untrusted certificate" message.  It says its untrusted because the certificate is not signed. This leads me to believe there is a certificate there, it just isn't set up correctly.  Can I make my own SSL Certificate for the barracuda VPN, or do I have to buy one?  Does barracuda provide a certificate for me? Could I call them up and get them to give me a certificate?

I have dabbled in web design/programming a bit, but I know NOTHING about these SSL Certificates other than what I've researched this morning.

If I can make my own, how do I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generating your own self signed SSL certificates is a bit of a challenge if you've only dabbled in web design.

A good tutorial is here http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

You should at least call Barracuda and ask them what they can help you with since you use their service.

Comment: You're welcome if you found this helpful you can up-vote it or set it as the answer.

Comment: i would if i had enough reputation

Comment: @CSharpDev not sure what you need it's 18 now though